# QUSER: What is SESSIONNAME value of console?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a freshly booted PC (Windows 10 Professional) with no one logged in yet. When I launch `QUSER` from another PC with the /S option to query that newly booted PC, I get:

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 userX                 console             1  Active      none   10/7/2020 14:46
```

`userX` is one of the user accounts created on that PC. It requires a password to log in, and nobody has logged in yet.

Why is there a user with SESSIONNAME `console` and STATE active? What does Active mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console session is basically the session of what is being displayed on screen. If its not console, then it is a session ID for remote login.

As you start your computer, even while not logged in, Windows 10 will start some of your programs in the background and as such, you are logged in despite being actually logged in. This is a change that occurred since a few windows builds. I think it started in 1809, but not sure.

The same is true, if you have multiple users logged in on the same pc, and you reboot, you'll see that those users get logged in again even though you are still the only person who logged in.

Active vs Idle vs Disconnected means if the user sees the screen or not. A console session is always active though, but on a remote session, if the user did not move the mouse or pressed keys for 5 minutes, a session becomes idle. If the user disconnects without logging off, they become disconnected.

Comment: At the risk of broadening out, what gets shown in this situation when a different user logs on to the PC locally? Does the not-really-logged-on user get shown as disconnected?

Comment: @roaima I'm actually not sure.